# OO coffee dispenser

Tags: c#, object-oriented

This picture inspired a contest between a few of my friends to rewrite this code in more proper OO style.

[image: coffee mug with code]

This is what I have come up with.
Any thoughts:

```
public enum CoffeeKind
{
    Black = 1,
    Cappuccino,
    Espresso
}

public class Coffee
{
    //Measured in celcius
    public int Temprature { get; set; } = 30;
    public bool HasMilk { get; set; }
    public int Sugar { get; set; }
    public CoffeeKind Kind { get; set; }
    public bool Cold => Temprature < 24;
}

public enum CupSize
{
    Small = 1,
    Medium,
    Large,
    ExtraLarge
}

public class Cup
{
    public static Cup SMALL = new Cup(CupSize.Small);
    public static Cup MEDIUM = new Cup(CupSize.Medium);
    public static Cup LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.Large);
    public static Cup EXTRA_LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.ExtraLarge);

    public static Dictionary<CupSize, Cup> Cups = new Dictionary<CupSize, Cup>
    {
        [CupSize.Small] = SMALL,
        [CupSize.Medium] = MEDIUM,
        [CupSize.Large] = LARGE,
        [CupSize.ExtraLarge] = EXTRA_LARGE
    };

    public CupSize Size { get; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public bool Empty => Amount == 0;
    public Coffee Coffee { get; set; }

    private Cup() : this(CupSize.Medium) { }
    private Cup(CupSize size)
    {
        Size = size;
    }

    public void Fill(CoffeeKind kind)
    {
        if (Empty)
        {
            Coffee = new Coffee { Kind = kind };
            Amount = SetAmountBySize(Size);
        }
    }

    private static int SetAmountBySize(CupSize size)
    {
        switch (size)
        {
            case CupSize.Small:
                return 100;
            case CupSize.Large:
                return 300;
            case CupSize.ExtraLarge:
                return 400;
            case CupSize.Medium:
            default:
                return 200;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public Cup Cup { get; set; }

    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public void GetCoffee(CupSize size, CoffeeKind kind)
    {
        Cup = Cup.Cups[size];
        Cup.Fill(kind);
    }

    public void Drink()
    {
        if (Cup?.Empty == false && Cup?.Coffee?.Cold == false)
        {
            Cup.Amount = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Drink(int amount)
    {
        if (Cup?.Empty == false && Cup?.Coffee?.Cold == false)
        {
            Cup.Amount -= amount;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    const int EXIT = -1;
    const int GET_COFFEE = 1;
    const int DRINK_COFFEE = 2;
    const int DRINK_AMOUNT = 3;

    //TODO change these to use values of enum - or just change the calls to them
    const int SMALL = 1;
    const int MEDIUM = 2;
    const int LARGE = 3;
    const int EXTRA_LARGE = 4;

    const int BLACK = 1;
    const int CAPPUCCINO = 2;
    const int ESPRESSO = 3;

    static Person person;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        person = new Person(firstName, lastName);

        var choice = GetUserAction();
        while (choice != EXIT)
        {
            if (choice == GET_COFFEE)
            {
                if (person?.Cup?.Empty == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Old coffee will be thrown out");
                }
                int cupSize = GetCupSize();
                int coffeeKind = GetCoffeKind();

                person.GetCoffee((CupSize)cupSize, (CoffeeKind)coffeeKind);
                Console.WriteLine($"Got a {person.Cup.Size.ToString()} size {person.Cup.Coffee.Kind.ToString()} coffee");
            }
            else if (choice == DRINK_COFFEE)
            {
                if (person?.Cup?.Empty == false)
                {
                    person.Drink();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can not drink without coffee!");
                }
            }

            choice = GetUserAction();
        }
    }

    private static int GetCoffeKind()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{BLACK}: Black");
        Console.WriteLine($"{CAPPUCCINO}: Cappuccino");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ESPRESSO}: Espresso");

        var result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (result < BLACK || result > ESPRESSO)
        {
            return GetCoffeKind();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static int GetCupSize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{SMALL}: {nameof(SMALL)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{MEDIUM}: Medium");
        Console.WriteLine($"{LARGE}: Large");
        Console.WriteLine($"{EXTRA_LARGE}: Extra Large");
        var result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (result < SMALL || result > EXTRA_LARGE)
        {
            return GetCupSize();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static int GetUserAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{GET_COFFEE}: Get coffee");
        // You can't drink coffee without a cup
        if (person?.Cup != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DRINK_COFFEE}: Drink coffee");
            Console.WriteLine($"{DRINK_AMOUNT}: Drink some coffee");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{EXIT}: Exit");
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35237/discussion-on-question-by-max-oo-coffee-dispenser).

Comment: In writing this code, please ensure that the implementation is compatible with the correct and agreed related standards for protocol support which are documented [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324).

Comment: It's such a letdown that you chose to write this in C# instead of Java. I mean, I usually like C# better, but you should choose the most appropriate tool for the job

Comment: Wow, talk about art imitating life!! The mug has a bug: A refilled cup never gets drunk.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're abusing the null propagation operator. E.g.

```
person = new Person(firstName, lastName);

var choice = GetUserAction();
while (choice != EXIT)
{
    if (choice == GET_COFFEE)
    {
        if (person?.Cup?.Empty == false)
        {
```

There is no way that person can be `null`. After being created, you never set it to anything else. Funnily enough, I thought it was going to be my most used feature of C#6 but I almost never use it.

---

C# generally never uses `SHOUT_CASE`. Your constants should be `PascalCase`.

---

If you're going to set an explicit value for one enum member, I'd say you should do it for them all:

```
public enum CoffeeKind
{
    Black = 1,
    Cappuccino = 2,
    Espresso = 3
}
```

I'd argue that your model is a bit off here. Espresso is black coffee i.e. it doesn't have milk in it.

```
public enum DrinkType
{
    FilterCoffee,
    Cappuccino,
    Espresso
}
```

I think that in general this isn't an enum. What if I want a decaff coffee? I think you need a drink class that can be composed.

---

I don't see the point in these fields:

```
public static Cup SMALL = new Cup(CupSize.Small);
public static Cup MEDIUM = new Cup(CupSize.Medium);
public static Cup LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.Large);
public static Cup EXTRA_LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.ExtraLarge);
```

You already have an enum - make sure you have implemented equality correctly and let people create their own <strike>mug</strike> cup.

---

As above:

```
public static Dictionary<CupSize, Cup> Cups = new Dictionary<CupSize, Cup>
{
    [CupSize.Small] = SMALL,
    [CupSize.Medium] = MEDIUM,
    [CupSize.Large] = LARGE,
    [CupSize.ExtraLarge] = EXTRA_LARGE
};
```

If you want to know about Cups you need to have a Cupboard:

```
public class Cupboard : IRepository<Cup>
{
    public Cup GetCupForPerson(Person p)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

You like your coffee cold ;)

```
public class Coffee
{
    //Measured in celcius
    public int Temprature { get; set; } = 30;
```

---

This is an odd method:

```
public void Drink()
{
    if (Cup?.Empty == false && Cup?.Coffee?.Cold == false)
    {
        Cup.Amount = 0;
    }
}
```

Why does it matter if the cup is empty?

1. If you're setting the Amount from 0 to 0 no one will even notice
2. I regularly get distracted and attempt to drink from an empty cup (sometimes even yesterday's)

You should either `TryDrink` if the action might not occur. Or, if you think your person (like me) is going to commit to drinking whatever is in that cup then you should always let them do it.

---

Watch out for typos: `GetCoffeKind` should be `GetCoffeeKind`.

Comment: "You like your coffee cold" lol. Nice answer!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Most important question I have is - what should the default temperature be? :)

Comment: I've implemented most of the feedback - the replacement for the `CoffeeKind` enum will take some more work though - I may just chnage it to a string for the meantime.

Comment: `"I don't see the point in these fields:" .."You already have an enum - make sure you have implemented equality correctly and let people create their own mug cup."` I am not sure how that would help. These fields (while extraneous as I can just force the user to supply the values I want through a ctor) are to enable quick access to pre-made cups.

Comment: `public static Dictionary<CupSize, Cup> Cups = new Dictionary<CupSize, Cup>
{
    [CupSize.Small] = SMALL,
    [CupSize.Medium] = MEDIUM,
    [CupSize.Large] = LARGE,
    [CupSize.ExtraLarge] = EXTRA_LARGE
};` This was to avoid an `if/else` in the `Program` class. An IRepository might be a bit much here ;)

Comment: @Max - an IRepository might be a bit much but I don't think it's the responsibility of the cup to know what cup sizes are available. I'd say 60C for coffee temp which is backed up by [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18226454) which I can't believe is real.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118647/oo-coffee-dispenser/118654?noredirect=1#comment221045_118647 - I may just drop the temperature. A cup should know what size it is though, correct? So maybe a `CupSize` struct with name and amount?

Comment: @Max - I'd say a cup should know its capacity yes and you can encode that as a set of predefined sizes a collection of immutable structs sounds like it could be a good choice.

Comment: +1. I have to do some real work now ;), but hope to try and work this feedback in later today. Will post a follow up question when I'm done

Comment: What if I want do drink my coffee out of a mug or [from a rubberduck](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/code-review-top-user-swag?cb=1#comment14663_6468)? What if, to me, 30ºC is too hot to be cold? How would one do that with your code?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the way to choose temperature is too wait for v2 ;)   mug == cup (based on JavaScript equality).   Drinking coffee out of a rubber duck is illegal under the Rome statute

Comment: love the term SHOUT_CASE - never saw that before  :)  Good one...

Answer (score 11):

Some quick remarks

#### `int GetCupSize()`, `int GetUserAction()` and `int GetCoffeKind()`

Using `int.TryParse()` would be better so any invalid entered character won't throw an exception.

#### `int SetAmountBySize(CupSize size)`

You don't really set an amount here. Try to find a better name.

#### General

Instead of `if (someBoolean == false)` you should use the more idiomatic way like
`if (!someBoolean)`.

Comment: Good catch on the `SetAmountBySize`. Will change the prefix from set to get. The booleanVar == false is because I'm using the Elvis operator so it it's a nullable

Comment: Would you say `!(bool)person?.Cup?.Empty` is better then `person?.Cup?.Empty == false`? if so why?

Comment: No, not really ;-) but nevertheless `person` wouln't be `null` (in main)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've fixed all the null checks.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say that there's a flaw in the logic of the code in the cup :). It should be more like the following:

```
Cup coffeeCup = new Cup(size);

while(true)
{
    if(cup.IsEmpty)
    {
        cup.Refill(coffeeType);
    }

    cup.Drink();
}
```

---

That being said, regarding your code, I'd just remove the following lines:

```
public static Cup SMALL = new Cup(CupSize.Small);
public static Cup MEDIUM = new Cup(CupSize.Medium);
public static Cup LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.Large);
public static Cup EXTRA_LARGE = new Cup(CupSize.ExtraLarge);
```

as they don't add anything of much relevance IMO.

Comment: `That being said, regarding your code, I'd just remove the following lines:` These are just convenience methods to get a quick pre-made cup of that size

Comment: @Max yeah, my point is that it adds nothing of much relevance. I'd prefer to go with the `new Cup(size)` instruction or with some factory methods like `MakeCup(size)` or `MakeSmallCup()` (or `MakeMediumCup()` and so on).

Comment: Thank you for that feedback. I'll play around some with all the feedback I've gotten and make a follow-up post(question)

Answer (score 7):

My comment:

> OO-wise this is a spilled cup. It's all over the place. You've got everything except a CupOfCoffee. The "dispenser" in the title can only be inferred w/in the spillage.
>
> Max: 
>   @radarbob would you like to elaborate please?

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    Person theDeveloper = new Person();
    Dispenser coffeeMaker = new Dispenser();

    CoffeeOrder whatIWant = GetUserAction();
    CupOfCoffee myCuppa = CoffeeMaker.Brew(whatIWant);
    theDeveloper.Drink(myCuppa);
}
```

**Object Oriented, enumerated**

- Structure
- Encapsulation
- Inversion of Control
- Modeling the domain. Per the OP there is a dispenser and a cup-of-coffee.
- Single Responsibility Principle - yes, it applies to methods.
- No properties have been harmed in the making of this code.

  - [Alan Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) said, paraphrasing, "If you're setting state directly, not using methods, you're doing it wrong."
- OO is fractal - Don't quit applying design just because:

  - "It's not much code"
  - "The method is small, we can put more code here"
  - Look! A class. That's OO! That's SOLID! Let the code barf commence.
- Reality, Interrupted:

  - `//TODO change these...` we have over 700 of these in our *production* code base. Code is like quick drying cement when released. it's solid (pun intended).
  - *This was just a quickly thrown together*

    - Been there, done that. And I've personally seen this manifest as the difference between spending 2 days in formal test and a 3 month test-fail-fix cycle of hell.

Comment: Thank you. In my current code base, the program *is* the dispenser. But your example has definitely enlightened me. I may simply create a separate project so as to not be side tracked by what I have already written

Comment: "OO is fractal - Don't quit applying design just because:". This was just a quickly thrown together first attempt. All the feedback I have received will help me rewrite it better.

Comment: I've learnt more about OO from asking about this silly little toy program than from any of the lectures/books that I have tried before :)